# Add new column based on value of an existing column

Tags: linux, text, awk, processing

I am trying to transform a delimited file into a table of data in linux. The meaning of value in certain columns are dependent the value in a separate column. How can I create additional columns based on the value of the column?

Depending on the value of column 2, i.e. 00 or 01 the interpretation of columns 3 and 4 are different. So if I had the following values.

```
A1,00,N1,T1
A1,01,N2,T2
A2,00,N3,T3
A2,01,N4,T4
```

The expected results should be as follows. Notice how I now have two new columns.

```
A1,00,N1,T1,N2,T2
A2,01,N3,T3,N4,T4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Expanding on @Cyrus' comment, you will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: @Cyrus. Fair point. I am very new to awk hence the ask for a start. My initial attempt was as follows. First pass duplicate the last two columns, then apply if condition and finally apply a "join".  

`$ cat a.txt`
`A1,00,N1,T1`
`A1,01,N2,T2`
`A2,00,N3,T3`
`A2,01,N4,T4`
`$ cat a.txt | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} $2 == "00" {$5 = ""; $6 = ""} $2 == "01" {$5 = $3; $6 = $4; $3 = ""; $4 = ""}; 1'`
`A1,00,N1,T1,,`
`A1,01,,,N2,T2`
`A2,00,N3,T3,,`
`A2,01,,,N4,T4`
`$`
Trying to find way to join data on 00 or 01.  Also have no idea about its performance if I have 200 million records  60 wide.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '                                #1
      {A[$1] = A[$1] FS $3 FS $4}          #2
  END {for(i in A) print i FS "00" A[i]}   #3
' file
A1,00,N1,T1,N2,T2
A2,00,N3,T3,N4,T4
```

1. Set Field Separator to comma.
2. On every line, set `Array[first-column]` to its current value followed by the third and fourth columns.
3. At the end, for every index, print the index name, a comma, the string "00", and the value of that index.

The end value of `A[A1]` is `,N1,T1,N2,T2`

Comment: Thank you @vintnes.

Comment: @jg1991 if this answers your question, please consider clicking the checkmark next to it to select it as best answer. If you have any further questions specific to this issue, let me know.

Comment: @vitnes.  My apologies.  I had a typo in the last line of my expected answer.  The values should have been `A2,01,N3,T3,N4,T4` instead of `A2,00,N3,T3,N4,T4`

Comment: Using the example in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228532/how-to-merge-separated-fields-in-rows-into-one-based-on-common-fields-in-awk-u)
Here is what I finally used.

$ cat join1.awk
BEGIN{
FS=OFS=","
}
{ key = $1 }
!seen[key]++ { keys[++total] = key }
{ values[key] = ( key in values ? values[key] FS $3 FS $4 : $3 FS $4 ) }
END {
    for (cnt=1; cnt<=total; cnt++)
    print keys[cnt], values[keys[cnt]]
}

$ # Result
$ cat a.txt | awk -f join1.awk
A1,N1,T1,N2,T2
A2,N3,T3,N4,T4
$
Thank you @vitnes